How I can point the `rtl8188eus` build towards the cloned android kernel source instead of the system one?
I try to build the https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus driver for android so I can load it into the emulator.
So far I have installed both android sdk, afterwards I have installed ndk
sdkmanager "ndk;27.0.11902837"

And I have exported the following environmental variables:
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/pcmagas/Android
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/pcmagas/Android

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator

export NDK_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME/ndk/27.0.11902837
export PATH=$PATH:$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin

Then I cloned the common kernel:
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git
cd common
git checkout android14-6.1-2024-04_r11

Then I cloned the driver source:
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus.git
cd rtl8188eus
 make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-android- CC=$TOOLCHAIN/x86_64-linux-android25-clang 

But I get the error:
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-112-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: /x86_64-linux-android25-clang: Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  You are using:           
/bin/sh: 1: /x86_64-linux-android25-clang: not found
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
  CC [M]  /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/rtl8188eus/core/rtw_cmd.o
/bin/sh: 1: /x86_64-linux-android25-clang: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/rtl8188eus/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1911: /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/rtl8188eus] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-112-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:2065: modules] Error 2


As you can see it is pointed towards the linuxc kernel and not towards the android kernel. How I can fix this?

Maybe try make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-android- CC=$TOOLCHAIN/x86_64-linux-android25-clang KSRC=~/dlink-decompile/common ?

So far I built my kernel like this:
mkdir -p /home/pcmagas/rtlwifiand
cd /home/pcmagas/rtlwifiand

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git
cd common
git checkout android14-6.1-2024-04_r11


make clean
make mrproper
make ARCH=x86_64 defconfig
make menuconfig
make scripts
make

cd ..

git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus.git
cd rtl8188eus

make -C /home/pcmagas/rtlwifiand/common ARCH=x86_64 KSRC=~/rtlwifiand/common KDIR=~/rtlwifiand/common


This resulted making a file named bzImage upon ~/rtlwifiand/common ommon/arch/x86/boot/bzImage I assume this is the final kernel with the driver.
